# how to overload Stripe's css

Tags: css, stripe-payments

I am currently using the Stripe payment system, and I would like to overload the css of the "description" part.
Unfortunately the code is generated by javascript and I can not make sure that my changes are taken into account.
In the browser console when I change everything is fine, but if I take the classes of Stripe, and I put them in "! Important", it does not work.

the code stripe :

```
handler.open({
            name: 'Test',
            description: 'Your transaction is insured securely by our payment partner Stripe. We never store sensitive data such as your card number or security code. This data is encrypted by Stripe and we do not have access to it.',
            currency: 'eur',
            amount: $('#toPay').text() * 100,
            email: email,
            allowRememberMe: false,
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The result :
[image]

as you can see the description text is not displayed in full

this is because of the part framed in red. And I would like to be able to overload it :
[image]

Has anyone ever had to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you set in your CSS `white-space: wrap` and `overflow: visible`. Just removing them from your console won't do anything, you have to override them.

Comment: Can you show us the except in the css you wrote?

Comment: You wil have to do the custom integration: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: Stripe's Checkout is served in an iframe for security reasons, so unfortunately there's no way you can override the CSS. if you need more customization i'd recommend using Elements, https://stripe.com/elements